# How TestNG communicate with Results Directory, scp or what?

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I want to know How TestNG communicate with Results Directory incase i want to provide external machine's directory path as TestNG outputdir ?

Comment: CIFS, NFS, or some other network file sharing service? What research have you done on this topic?

Comment: Let me explain my problem again : I am executing tests via Jenkins on Windows but want to store the testNG results in another server which is Linux machine.But I am not sure how to do that.